# Stopping curl from sending Authorization header on 302 redirect

Tags: redirect, curl

I am using `curl` to connect to a REST API. The REST API uses a Bearer token in the `Authorization` header. So my `curl` call looks like this:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <token>" https://www.example.com/api
```

This API has started returning a 302 redirect in response to my API call.

I added the `-L` option to instruct `curl` to follow the redirect:

```
curl -L -H "Authorization: Bearer <token>" https://www.example.com/api
```

Now `curl` does perform the redirect.

Here's the problem: curl is sending the custom `Authorization` header along with the redirect. I have verified this using the `-v` option so it shows me the headers it's sending.

The new server (Windows Azure I believe) actually fails the call with a 400 status code because it does not like the `Authorization` header. The redirected URL does not want an authorization header at all.

So, how can I get `curl` to not send my custom `Authorization` header on redirects? Or is there another way to specify the `Authorization` header that will avoid the issue.

Comment: Did you find a workaround for this?

Comment: Not using `curl` alone. I ended up abandoning the `-L` option and parsing the `302` result myself.

Answer (score 9):

This has been fixed in [curl 7.58.0](https://curl.haxx.se/changes.html#7_58_0). Specifically to avoid leaking the credentials to the redirect location.

With curl 7.58.0 it should work without making any changes. If you still want to pass through the credentials, you have to use the `--location-trusted` option.

There are no workarounds for earlier versions except for *not* using the `-L` option, parsing the `Location` field yourself and doing a separate request to the new location. (as mentioned by Matt Houser)

You can find some more information on this change [here](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/adv_2018-b3bf.html).

Comment: Thanks for this. The version of `curl` included in macOS 10.13.6 is 7.54.0 so the workaround is to install a more recent `curl` manually, perhaps using Homebrew: `brew install curl` and follow the instructions to put it in your PATH since it's keg-only.