# Following a redirect in cURL without including headers

Tags: curl

I have the following cURL command:

```
curl -H "Authorization: token $GITHUB_TOKEN" \
    -H "Accept: application/octet-stream" \
    $TARBALL_ASSET_URL -O $filename
```

The `$TARBALL_ASSET_URL` is the URL of an asset attached to a GitHub release. What happens when I hit this endpoint is that GitHub responds with a 302 redirect to a pre-signed Amazon S3 download URL. When it hits that URL, however, cURL includes the original `Authorization` header, that I used to authenticate with the GitHub API. The S3 server then sees the `Authorization` header and rejects the request, since the UR already has a signature and AWS rejects any requests that include multiple attempts at authentication.

Is there support in `curl` for ensuring that the specified headers are only used on the first request in the redirect chain? Or should I simply not follow redirects and do this manually as curl commands?

Answer (score 1):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37865875/stopping-curl-from-sending-authorization-header-on-302-redirect) is not quite a duplicate of this question as posed, but it is a duplicate of my specific use case. It turns out that I was using cURL v7.54, and as of v7.58 the `Authorization` header specifically is *never* passed along on redirect, for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You can add -L (follow redirect) to your command. So it will be :

```
curl -L -H "Authorization: token $GITHUB_TOKEN" \
    -H "Accept: application/octet-stream" \
    $TARBALL_ASSET_URL -O $filename
```