# How do I curl against a git.io URL generated from a private repo?

Tags: github, curl

I have a script that I'd like to be able to access via a curl command against its `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/...` location. Using git.io, it's really easy to shorten this URL to something like `https://git.io/ABCDE`.

But there's an issue related to the fact that my script exists in a private repository. If I directly curl against the `githubusercontent` URL, I get 404: Not Found. I'm able to bypass this by passing an authorization header with the request, e.g.

```
$ curl -H "Authorization: token <My Github Personal Access Token>" \
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/...
> !#/bin/bash
... # rest of script
```

However, when I use my shortened URL, I don't get anything back. Not even a 404.

```
$ curl -H "Authorization: token <My Github Personal Access Token>" \
https://git.io/ABCDE
$
```

Anyone know what's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way a URL shortener works is that it issues some sort of 3xx-series HTTP status code that redirects you to the new location, and then you make your request against that new location.  However, by default, curl does not follow redirects, so all you see when you make your request is the output from git.io, which in this case is nothing.

If you want to follow redirects, then you should use the `-L` option to curl, which will make it follow redirects.  Note that this can be insecure in many cases when passing credentials, since any credentials passed with `-H` will be passed to any remote server that the data is redirected to.  In this case, that's what you want, but it can be a security problem in other cases if the credentials were only intended for the original server.

Comment: Thank you! This is an awesome answer, and explains exactly what I needed to know.

Comment: Note that you must also use `--location-trusted` as of curl 7.58.0. See this relevant comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50005430/11899595